# Проблема с $(document).on('click'...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Шаблон подгружаются аяксом. В шаблоне таблица и есть кнопки `<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default">...</button>`. При нажатии на одну из этих кнопок, на нажатую кнопку ставится класс `btn-success`. Но перед этим надо проеверить, есть ли у кнопки атрибут `disabled`. И проверка не проходит.

```
var SetMainImage = function () {
    var $btnMainImg = jQuery('[data-btn-img-main]');

    jQuery(document).on('click', '[data-btn-img-main]', function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        console.log($this);
        if($this.prop('disabled', false))
        {
            $btnMainImg.prop('disabled', false);
            $btnMainImg.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-default');
            var $imgId = $this.parent().parent().data('product-img-id');

        }
    })
};
```

Проверка не происходит потому что `jQuery(this)` это массив, а в нем обьект нажатой кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если обратиться как к массиву `jQuery(this)[0]`, то возвращается только html а не обьект jQuery.
Как получить нажатую кнопку как обьект jQuery?

UPD: Я убрал `$btnMainImg` и код теперь выглядит так

```
var SetMainImage = function () {

    jQuery(document).on('click', '[data-btn-img-main]', function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        console.log($this);
        if($this.prop('disabled', false))
        {


        }
    })
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И всеравно массив,а не объект нажатой кнопки

Comment: В jQuery при клике `jQuery(this)` и есть объект нажатой кнопки. В скрине ошибка не от этого куска кода. `$btnMainImg` у вас действительно массив, объект кнопки по индексу можно получить кажется так: `jQuery($btnMainImg[0])`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev обновил вопрос. Так тоже не выходит `jQuery($btnMainImg[0])`

Comment: да, у вас проблема во втором преобразовании объекта jquery. `var $this = this` - так будет работать